# iOS In-App Purchase (Consumable) - Server Timeout

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

I have a question about a particular situation with In-App Purchases.

We have a consumable for buying coins in our app:

- Use buys a $.99 coin pack with IAP
- We send a request to our server to record the purchase and add the coins to their account (these coins are shared between multiple devices, our server does the work here)
- Complete transaction for IAP

Problem is, what we supposed to do if the request to our server times out or fails?  The user spent the money, but will never get the coins.  And if they try to purchase again at that point, it will give them an error saying the purchase hasn't downloaded.

I have seen a "Restore Transactions" option, but not sure how to apply it here.  I'd rather not have a button for it somewhere in the app.

Don't worry this app isn't released yet, and this app is written in C# with MonoTouch, but Objective-C answers are welcome.

Comment: Maybe generate a transaction ID? If the app detects that a transaction has been attempted recently and your server has no record of the transaction ID add the purchase to the server. Technically this would be "hackable", so I'd suggest using a seeded random number generator that you can verify was created by you, not the user.

Comment: Is there an "Apple suggested" way to go about it?  I guess I could save the information for the purchase and recover on app open.

Comment: I feel like I read something on this recently, let me see if I can find it.

Comment: Apple suggests the restoreCompletedTransactions method. I'd assume that you are storing that the transaction has been "completed" once you receive the payment.

Comment: I believe restoreCompletedTransactions method won't work since you wouldn't want to credit user every time she installs the program on a new device. Save the purchase information somewhere on the device and try to re-send the request to your server as soon as possible.

Comment: Keep a local list of timed out transactions, and attempt redownload until succeeding. Register each task after charging the user but before contacting your server (which might time out), or on time out (doesn't matter). Delete each task from the list once its download succeeds. Also, consider restoreCompletedTransactions as noted by others. **Edit** I'm not sure how restoring works with consumable products (haven't used yet)

Comment: When storing the users account on your own server, what do you use as the identifier? Their Apple ID?

Comment: We use their email address or Facebook ID, which doesn't have to match their iTunes account.

Answer (score 1):

Restore transactions would do it. It simply redownloads the purchase again. Take a look at the fifth post here:

http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/359109

Here is the code to implement it:

InAppPurchaseManager > MySKPaymentObserver:

```
    public override void PaymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished (SKPaymentQueue queue)
        {
            foreach(SKPaymentTransaction transaction in queue.Transactions)
            {

                #if DEBUG
                Console.WriteLine("Restoring Transaction " + transaction.Payment.ProductIdentifier);
                #endif
                theManager.restoreTransaction(transaction);
            }
        }
```

Here is how to call the code in your game:

```
 app = new InAppPurchaseManager ();
 app.LoadStore();
 SKPaymentQueue.DefaultQueue.RestoreCompletedTransactions();
```

Comment: Does this work properly for a consumable purchase?  I don't think it would, it sound like the could get free coins by pushing the restore button.

Answer (score 1):

The way i have done is by saving a failed transaction in NSUserDefaults. So, everytime the app comes from background , it checks user defaults for any failed transactions and then retries again.

Am not sure if its the right way. But, i would like to know if there is a better way to do it.